# 500 error in wordpress plugin when using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a plugin for my wordpress site which when a select box is changed it then changes the select options below by calling from the wordpress database.

For the life of me I can not get this to work.

Here is the wordpress coding:

```
function ubl_ug_load_ajax(){
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'ubl-unlimited-galleries-image'){

        wp_enqueue_script('ubl-ajax', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/ubl-ajax.js', array('jquery'));

    } else {
        return;
    }
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','ubl_ug_load_ajax');

function ubl_uimages_page(){

global $wpdb;

    // GET CATEGORIES
    $getcatsforimages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, galleryname FROM ubl_galleries");

    if($getcatsforimages){

        // ADD MODE
        if(!isset($_GET['ublmode'])){

            $ublerrors = array();

            $galleryname = '';
            $gallerycats = '';

            if(isset($_POST['issent'])){

                // do something

            }

            $output = '

                <style>
                h1{padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;margin:0px;}
                h3{padding:40px 0px 10px 0px;margin:0px;}
                .wrap{margin:0px;padding:15px;width:50%;}
                .widget .widget-top, .postbox h3, .stuffbox h3{padding:5px 10px; color:#1e1e1e}
                .widget, #widget-list .widget-top, .postbox, #titlediv, #poststuff .postarea, .stuffbox{
                    background-color:white;
                }
                .postbox .inside, .stuffbox .inside{padding:20px;background-color:whiteSmoke;}
                .red{color:red;}
                .green{color:green;}
                .regular-text{margin-bottom:20px;}
                h4{margin:0px;padding:8px 0px 3px 0px;}
                .inside > p{padding:3px;margin:0px;}
                hr{border-color:white;background-color:white;}
                .stuffbox img{max-width:300px;height:auto;}
                </style>

            ';

            $output .= '<div class="wrap">';

            $output .= '<h1>Add New Gallery</h1>';
            $output .= '<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            $output .= '<input name="issent" type="hidden" value="1" />';
            $output .= '<div class="stuffbox"><h3><label>Gallery Details</label></h3><div class="inside">';
            $output .= '<h4>Gallery Name</h4><p>';
            $output .= '<select name="galleryname" class="galleryname">';
            foreach($getcatsforimages as $getc){
            $output .= '<option value="'.$getc->id.'">'.$getc->galleryname.'</option>';
            }
            $output .= '</select>';
            $output .= '<hr>';
            $output .= '<h4>Gallery Categories &amp Slude</h4><p class="gallerycats"></p>';
            $output .= '<p>Please Choose A Category</p>';
            $output .= '</div></div>';
            $output .= '</form>';
            $output .= '</div>';

            echo $output;

        }

    } else { ?>
    <div class="wrap"><h1>Please Create Galleries First</h1></div>
    <?php }

}
```

Here is the ajax file coding:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery(".galleryname").change(function(){

            var ubl_get_results=jQuery(this).val();
            var url = '../wp-content/plugins/ul/ajax.php'

            data = {
                 ajaxid: ubl_get_results,
                };

            jQuery.post(url, data , function (data) {

                //jQuery('.gallerycats').html(response);

                alert(data);

            });

        return false;
        });

});
```

Then here is the php file which the ajax is posting too:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['ajaxid'])){

    echo 'this works';

} else {

    echo 'Could Not Do This';

}
```

Comment: For 500 error, can you change your logs to see what the error is actually?

Comment: I don't see how your jQuery file does anything with a checkbox or with it's options when it's selected or not.

Comment: @BramVanroy it does nothing yet, i am just getting it to work when it changes it at present. As you can see by the jquery it calls the .galleryname select form and when it changes it then calls the ajax

Comment: Remember that 500 is "internal server error", which usually means you can get the details from your web server log. Don't forget to enable verbose error logging with PHP, and also Apache, so it doesn't filter important information. If you are on development environment you should have done it already. Debugging information is invaluable in your case, especially if you are new to JQuery as you say. Also, try to debug each component of your system separately - for instance, try fetching the PHP script with your browser first, and see what you get.

Comment: @JureC. Where do i change my logs?

Comment: Did you take a look at your server error log ? Did you read this https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins ?

Comment: @amn I am new to ajax and do not know where or how to change my logs, i have done the query within the php section and it calls fine

Comment: @Robert, AJAX has very little to do with server logs. What you are after is either Apache (or some other webserver) configuration. And also PHP, by extension. What's your setup?